# Parsing JSON Not Showing out of range

Tags: java, android, json

I'm working on parsing JSON file in my java and the JSON file goes like this

```
{"System":[{"System1":{"DisplayName":"fabcd","InternalName":"AD","SystemCode":"0001","SystemName":"vnid"},"System2":{"DisplayName":"akdfkajfl","InternalName":"AD","SystemCode":"0001","SystemName":"kjdfkafdk"}}]}
```

I cannot access the all objects inside "System" array. Please help me on this. My code is this

```
Systems = jObj.getJSONArray("System");
                Log.d("Array", Systems.toString());
                JSONObject first = Systems.getJSONObject(0);
                Log.d("CSystems",first.toString());

                // looping through All Contacts
                for(int i = 0; i <=Systems.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = Systems.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.d("SubSystems", Systems.getString(0));

                }
```

Thanks.

Comment: is this a valid json check here http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Yes. It is. I tried it before I parse it.

Comment: Just a quick hunch, it seems like i<=System.length() is the problem, i starts at 0, change to i < Systems.length(), so that i doesn't go over the length of the array.

Comment: @user2955143 what does this `Log.d("SubSystems", Systems.getString(0));` log ?`

Comment: @IsraelTabadi: I manually passed 0. Even that won't work for to parse that. Failing to get that "system1".

Comment: @user2955143 it would be easier if you change your json. if not check the below. there is 1 json array. System1 and System2 are json objects

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `for` loop be looping over `first` instead of `Systems`? (With changes to account for the fact it's an object, not an array.)

Comment: But I want to iterate through all the systems. So I used for loop.

Comment: I didn't say you shouldn't use a for loop. I said that your loop should iterate over the keys of `first` instead of the elements of `Systems`. Something like this: `String key; for(Iterator it = first.keys(); it.hasNext(); key = it.next()) { JSONObject sys = first.get(key); ... }`. Basically you need to go one level deeper down the JSON hierarchy - or, as Raghunandan suggested, change the JSON itself so it's one level shallower (if you have control over the JSON format).

Answer (score 0):

To parse

```
      try
      {
          JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject("My Json string");
          JSONArray jr = jObj.getJSONArray("System");
          JSONObject jb= jr.getJSONObject(0);
          JSONObject system1 = jb.getJSONObject("System1");
          String name =  system1.getString("DisplayName");
          String internalname = system1.getString("InternalName");
          String SystemCode = system1.getString("SystemCode");
          String SystemName = system1.getString("SystemName");
          JSONObject system2 = jb.getJSONObject("System2");
          String name1= system2.getString("DisplayName");
          String internalname1 = system2.getString("InternalName");
          String SystemCode1 = system2.getString("SystemCode");
          String SystemName1 = system2.getString("SystemName");
          Log.i("..........",name+"..."+internalname+"..."+SystemCode+"..."+SystemName);
          Log.i("..........",name1+"..."+internalname1+"..."+SystemCode1+"..."+SystemName1);

      }catch(Exception e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

or

Same as above.

```
      try
      {
          JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject("My json string");
          JSONArray jr = jObj.getJSONArray("System");
          for(int i = 0; i<jr.length(); i++){
              JSONObject c = jr.getJSONObject(i);
              for(int j = 1;j<3; j++){
              JSONObject jb = c.getJSONObject("System"+(j));
              Log.i("SubSystems", jb.getString("DisplayName"));
              Log.i("SubSystems", jb.getString("InternalName"));
              Log.i("SubSystems", jb.getString("SystemCode"));
              Log.i("SubSystems", jb.getString("SystemName"));
              }
          }

      }catch(Exception e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

or change your json to

```
{
    "System": [
        {
            "DisplayName": "fabcd",
            "InternalName": "AD",
            "SystemCode": "0001",
            "SystemName": "vnid"
        },
        {
            "DisplayName": "akdfkajfl",
            "InternalName": "AD",
            "SystemCode": "0001",
            "SystemName": "kjdfkafdk"
        }
    ]
}
```

To parse. Changing json to above parsing is much more easier.

```
 try
          {
              JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject("My json string);
              JSONArray jr = jObj.getJSONArray("System");
              for(int i = 0; i<jr.length(); i++){
                  JSONObject c = jr.getJSONObject(i);
                  Log.i("SubSystems", c.getString("DisplayName"));
                  Log.i("SubSystems", c.getString("InternalName"));
                  Log.i("SubSystems", c.getString("SystemCode"));
                  Log.i("SubSystems", c.getString("SystemName"));

              }

          }catch(Exception e)
          {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

You can also look at https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/